# Isomorphisms and characteristics

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $\phi: A \to B$ is a ring isomorphism, I have to proof that $char A= char B$.

I have already prove that $char A= char B$ supposing that $Char B=n \not=0$

But what happens if Char B=0? How can I prove it?

Comment: What happens if $Char(A)\neq 0=Char(B)$?

Comment: I usually accept the answers that are useful for me. But in this case I didn't understand it very good and I didn't upvote. In any case, do I have any obligation to do it? You can upvote the answer too if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi:A\to B$, with $a\mapsto a'$, is an isomorphism, $1\mapsto 1'$, $1+1\mapsto 1'+1'$,  $1+1+1\mapsto 1'+1'+1',\&c\;$ and all $1',1'+1',1'+1'+1',\ldots$ are distinct by ${\rm char} A=0$ and injectivity of $\phi$.

The same works assuming ${\rm char\; }B=0$ by looking at $\phi^{-1}$.